# Trying to rebuild broken records with regex

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I am trying to rebuild csv files with a loop and regex matching.  My problem is that records have line breaks in them and it splits them to multiple rows.  I have a loop to rebuild the broken lines, but I need to ensure that I match on every possible field so that it is picked up by the loop correctly.

I have this regex string so far from researching other topics with regex to clean csv files.  I am not very strong with regex so there are likely inefficiencies with this method:

```
(?:\"|^\")(\"\"|[\\w\\W]*?)(?=\",|\"$)|(?:,(?!\")|^(?!\"))([^,]*?)(?=$|,)|($\n|\r)|(?=\\,\"|^\")(.*[^\"]$)
```

I am aware of the following types of records I will encounter:

> unquoted string followed by a comma
>
> quoted string followed by a comma
>
> quoted strings containing embedded commas/new lines/quotes

It seems as though the line breaks are causing issues with records that contain a beginning quote and then a linebreak inside the quote which bumps the rest of the record to the next line.  My loop can repair it if the regex matches the partially quoted string.

Comment: Why don't you just use a text qualifier?

Comment: I am ingesting data through SSIS.  The goal is to clean the file with a c# script to replace any custom delimiters with a comma and to strip out quotes after removing embedded delimiters, text qualifiers and quotes.  SSIS is very picky with stuff embedded in text qualifiers from my experience.

Comment: Have you actually tried importing this via the vanilla SSIS Flat File Source?  If you specify your delimiters and qualifiers in the connection manager this should import without issue, line breaks and all.

Comment: The issue is that the files are not in a static format and the package is an established method to load many different formats in one place. Using the flat file managers and format files will make things too cumbersome.  There is a need to scrub all files to standardize their format before loading to a table.  The data contains many characters and instanced that need to be stripped out and transformed before they make it to the table.

Comment: This is all very relevant contextual information that you should have added to your question from the start.  If you don't provide a sufficient representation of you personal situation you are obviously not going to get very relevant answers.  Remember that we do this for free to help you.  Do please try to help us in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

## You have said that you are importing this file via SSIS and that you think you need to handle all the special data cases due to the nature of this file.  This is not the case and you are essentially trying to replicate the significant amount of work that has gone into making SSIS as powerful as it is.

Using your sample file added in a comment previously I have crated a text file and then imported it using SSIS:

```
Case/Matter Name,Number,Open Date,Practice Area,Description,Case Closed,Notes[\r\n]
john smith,1234,10/01/2013,Practice1,"Something happened, something broke",true,"Attourney 1 (03/05/2014): Case Closed[\r]
Case Closed"[\r\n]
"john, smith",2345,04/25/2014,Practice2,"Something, ""happened"", something broke",true,"Attourney 1 (09/26/2014): Closed[\r]
Closed per Instruction[\r]
--------[\r]
Closed Account3 (05/27/2014): Status as of 5/27/14[\r]
some text, about why the account was closed[\r]
"
```

The SSIS Flat File Connection Manager has:

- A `Text Qualifier` of `"`
- A `Header Row Delimiter` of `{CR}{LF}`
- A `Row Delimiter` of `{CR}{LF}`
- A `Column Delimiter` of `Comma {,}`

Which was imported into a SQL Server table using a `Flat File Source` that fed into an `OLE DB Destination` without issue.  When selecting the data from the table the resulting output is as follows:

```
+------------------+--------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Case Matter Name | Number | Open Date  | Practice Area | Description                            | Case Closed | Notes                                              |
+------------------+--------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| john smith       | 1234   | 10/01/2013 | Practice1     | Something happened, something broke    | true        | Attourney 1 (03/05/2014): Case Closed              |
|                  |        |            |               |                                        |             | Case Closed                                        |
+------------------+--------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| john, smith      | 2345   | 04/25/2014 | Practice2     | Something, "happened", something broke | true        | Attourney 1 (09/26/2014): Closed                   |
|                  |        |            |               |                                        |             | Closed per Instruction                             |
|                  |        |            |               |                                        |             | --------                                           |
|                  |        |            |               |                                        |             | Closed Account3 (05/27/2014): Status as of 5/27/14 |
|                  |        |            |               |                                        |             | some text, about why the account was closed        |
+------------------+--------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Put simply, you are hugely over thinking this problem and some back to basics functional testing before launching into a huge duplication of work that SSIS can already do for you would go a long way.

Comment: This method could work after files are in a standard format, but I have many different formats that through this solution.  What I need is to clean these and other instances (for example cases of scientific notation from excel sheets) with a script prior to loading.  It is more effective to rebuild the files in a standard format prior to loading to prevent multiple connection managers.

Comment: @BP2401  What changes would require different connection managers?  Different columns?  Any differences in the actual data should be handled in your database, including expanding Excel scientific notation, of which SQL Server is very capable of accurately parsing.

Comment: @BP2401  I mean, I am assuming you are following best practice and loading into a staging area before production?

Comment: Yes, the file gets dumped into a staging table with all varchar fields before actual datatype transformations begin.  The files have variable number of fields and sometimes they are not in the same order from start to finish.  No reason to use a connection manager with bulk insert when you can force everything into one standard.  My method to load column order dynamically works, I am just trying to parse with a C# script to rebuild the broken records from linebreaks and remove quotes and embedded delimiters.  Much easier to load when I can force everything to conform to one standard.

Comment: @BP2401 There is nothing wrong with having multiple connection managers. If you are talking about 30+ different file formats, look into something like [Biml](https://varigence.com/BimlExpress) to generate your imports from a generic metadata based framework. From my experience you are coming at this from completely the wrong direction and are creating a nightmare of future maintenance to ensure your "one-size-fits-all" CSV parser remains functional.  I cannot help you with the regex but would strongly recommend against trying to reinvent the wheel - use tools already developed by the industry.